# Is it possible to initialize brush in ggplot in a shiny app?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a `shiny` app and I want a `ggplot` with a `brush` at the start, so the user does not need to select certain area of interest every time the app starts. Later of course user can select different area. Here is an example to start with:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(plotOutput('plotA', brush = brushOpts(id = 'plotA_brush')),
                 plotOutput('plotZ')),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    pollData <- reactivePoll(60 * 1000, session,
                             checkFunc = function(){ Sys.time() },
                             valueFunc = function(){ data.frame(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)))})
    output$plotA <- renderPlot({
      dt <- pollData()
      ggplot(dt, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
    })
    ranges <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)
    observe({
      brush <- input$plotA_brush
      if(!is.null(brush)) {
        ranges$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
        ranges$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)
      } else {
        ranges$x <- NULL
        ranges$y <- NULL
      }
    })
    output$plotZ <- renderPlot({
      dt <- pollData()
      ggplot(dt, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges$x, ylim = ranges$y)
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: Initialize it to what though? It starts out "initialized" to the whole area. I suspect you want to initialize it to a particular portion, but what portion? Anything else that is smaller than the whole thing?

Comment: Yes, anything else that is smaller than the whole thing. In this particular example let's say I want `x` to be in the range from 25 to 75 and `y` from minimum to maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

In the code below I've added just a few lines.  First, I've added `set.seed(42)` so that the graphics are reproducible.  Second, there is a `dput(brush)` that has been commented out.  This was helpful for identifying the initial brush that I wanted to have.  Lastly, The in the `observe` environment controlling the `ranges` I have added a `if` `else` set to use the default `brush` is it is a `NULL` value from the `input$plotA_brush` object.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(42)

runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(plotOutput('plotA', brush = brushOpts(id = 'plotA_brush')),
                 plotOutput('plotZ')),
  server = function(input, output, session) {


    pollData <- reactivePoll(60 * 1000, session,
                             checkFunc = function(){ Sys.time() },
                             valueFunc = function(){ data.frame(x = 1:100, y = cumsum(rnorm(100)))})
    output$plotA <- renderPlot({
      dt <- pollData()
      ggplot(dt, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
    })
    ranges <- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)
    observe({
      if (is.null(input$plotA_brush)) {
        brush <- structure(list(xmin = 14.313925002001, xmax = 39.942241912585, ymin = 1.1077251080591, ymax = 5.5028180250535, mapping = structure(list( x = "x", y = "y"), .Names = c("x", "y")), domain = structure(list( left = -3.95, right = 104.95, bottom = -4.07771077213569, top = 9.69030145758825), .Names = c("left", "right", "bottom", "top")), range = structure(list(left = 32.3904099935947, right = 674.020527857828, bottom = 368.859578048224, top = 5.47945189149413), .Names = c("left", "right", "bottom", "top")), log = structure(list(x = NULL, y = NULL), .Names = c("x", "y")), direction = "xy", brushId = "plotA_brush", outputId = "plotA"), .Names = c("xmin", "xmax", "ymin", "ymax", "mapping", "domain", "range", "log", "direction", "brushId", "outputId"))
      } else {
        brush <- input$plotA_brush
      }
      # dput(brush)  # Useful for finding the initial brush
      if(!is.null(brush)) {
        ranges$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
        ranges$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)
      } else {
        ranges$x <- NULL
        ranges$y <- NULL
      }
    })
    output$plotZ <- renderPlot({
      dt <- pollData()
      ggplot(dt, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges$x, ylim = ranges$y)
    })
  }
))
```

The initial starting page looks like this:

[image]